# Adding top/bottom padding to .col-xx when they stack in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using bootstrap 3.3, what's the correct way to add padding between columns once they go from horizontal to stacked vertical. For example, if I have the following code below, when they stack vertical at the xs breakpoint, the top block and bottom block are sandwiched together without padding/margin between them. I don't want to put padding on the col-sm-7 because I don't need it there when the columns are side by side. I suppose one way would be to make a specific class that uses media queries to add padding at the xs breakpoint, but curious if there are any other solutions out there...or if I'm missing something in bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div>Plan 1: Basic</div>
        <div>$99 per month</div>
        <div>4 of 5 slots used</div>
    </div>
    <!-- WHEN THESE STACK I NEED SPACE BETWEEN THEM -->
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="text-right">
            <div><button class="btn btn-sm btn-block">Manage Users</button></div>
            <div><button class="btn btn-sm btn-block">Manage Plan</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no top and bottom padding on `.row` and `.col-X-X` in Bootstrap, the reason why you see vertical spacing in their examples is because the content inside the .col-X-X is inside a `p`, `ul`, `form`, `h1-h6`, etc., tag which has top and bottom margin. If you used, instead of `div`, a `p` tag you would get some vertical space. If that's not agreeable, generally I make a vertical spacer like this:

```
<hr class="vertical-spacer visible-xs">
```

Using the responsive utilities to indicate when you want that space to show up.

**CSS**

```
hr.vertical-spacer {
  border: 0px;
  background: none;
  margin: 2% 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*Adding padding at the max-width media query would also work, however you would get extra spacing when you do put your content inside `p`, `h1-h6`, and so forth, and this would not be consistent or recommended, that's why there's no padding/margin directly on the `.col-X-X` classes by default.*

Comment: Okay, that's for the suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Simply adding this html in the top can give you a small space.

```
<div class="row">.</div>
```